# How to stop tile animation in Unity TileSystem?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, tile

I'm trying to understand tileSystem build in Unity, and i don't know how to stop animation in AnimatedTiles.

Once animation is started, there is no way i can think of to stop this. I'm working on Unity 2018.3.2f1, but i think that TileSystem is similar in next versions.

Only code in AnimatedTile handling animation is:

```
public override void GetTileData(Vector3Int location, ITilemap tileMap, ref TileData tileData)
        {
            tileData.transform = Matrix4x4.identity;
            tileData.color = Color.white;
            if (m_AnimatedSprites != null && m_AnimatedSprites.Length > 0)
            {
                tileData.sprite = m_AnimatedSprites[0];
                tileData.colliderType = m_TileColliderType;
            }
        }

        public override bool GetTileAnimationData(Vector3Int location, ITilemap tileMap, ref TileAnimationData tileAnimationData)
        {
            if (m_AnimatedSprites.Length > 0)
            {
                tileAnimationData.animatedSprites = m_AnimatedSprites;
                tileAnimationData.animationSpeed = Random.Range(m_MinSpeed, m_MaxSpeed);
                tileAnimationData.animationStartTime = m_AnimationStartTime;
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

I want to stop animation after some time (like 3 seconds) or after last frame. Any help would be appritiated!

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? This person and myself also have the same question: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/166930/stop-animated-tile-from-looping-unity2d-c?rq=1

Comment: I got some workaround for a moment. You just wait for animation to end and just replace animated tile for static tile with first image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after some time a got workaround and it looks like this :

```
public class TileBump : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Transform m_GridParent;
    public GameObject m_TileMap_Prefab;
    public AnimatedTile m_tilePrefabAnimated;
    public Tile m_tilePrefabStatic;

    private Tilemap map;

    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(EStart());
    }

    public IEnumerator EStart()
    {
        GameObject t = Instantiate(m_TileMap_Prefab, m_GridParent);
        map = t.GetComponent<Tilemap>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            {
                map.SetTile(new Vector3Int(i, j, 0), m_tilePrefabAnimated);
                StartCoroutine(Operation(new Vector3Int(i, j, 0)));
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.3f);
            }
        }

    }

    public IEnumerator Operation(Vector3Int x)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(m_tilePrefabAnimated.m_AnimatedSprites.Length / m_tilePrefabAnimated.m_AnimationSpeed);
        map.SetTile(x, m_tilePrefabStatic);
    }
}
```

BUT. What i understood here is that tiles are not for that. Every tile in TileMap refer to ScriptableObject, so every animation will be same in every frame.

However if someone need this kind of effect, its one way to do it.

Comment: What is the script attached to?

Comment: Any gamobject really. Just remember that you need Grid Component on gameobject connected to m_GridParent variable, and Tilemap + Tilemap Renderer on TileMapPrefab.